# Can't add contextmenu to TreePanel

Tags: javascript, extjs3

I use ExtJS 3.4

I have a treepanel with nodes. And me need to create contextmenu for everyone node. So, I am trying to add contextmenu, but get TypeError:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getXY' of undefined

What's wrong? Help me, please :)

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    var menustore = {

        text: "Languages",
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: "C#",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "C++",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "Java",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "PHP",
            leaf: true
        }]
    }

    new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        title: 'Languages',
        root: menustore,
        width: 170,
        rootVisible: false,
        id: 'tree-panel',
        listeners: {
            contextmenu: function (view, record, item, index, event) {

                ContextMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
                    id: 'contxtmenu',
                    items: [{
                        text: 'Edit',
                    }]
                });

                ContextMenu.showAt(event.getXY());
                event.stopEvent();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

UPD:

I changed parameters and it works now =)

```
listeners: {
    contextmenu: function (node, event){
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The second parameter for the event is the browser event, not the record.

Comment: @evan-trimboli Thanks =)